# AttributeError: module 'strawberry.experimental' has no attribute 'pydantic'

Tags: pydantic, python-3.9, python-poetry, strawberry-graphql

I recently upgraded to python 3.9.17 from 3.7.11 and changed poetry version to 1.3.2 . However I am getting errors when I am trying to run that application. I am using strawberry-gql too

However I am getting

```
AttributeError: module 'strawberry.experimental' has no attribute 'pydantic'
```

in the place where I have

```
@strawberry.experimental.pydantic.type(model=DsccError, all_fields=True)
```

Is pydantic moved to something else from `experimental`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, pydantic as moved to v2 with some breaking change, check your installed version and fallback to 1.10

Comment: superb. I am marking as accepted